# What are the basics about Tomcat , that a java developer must be aware of?

Tags: tomcat

Can some one please share links where i can learn about the basics of the Apache Tomcat . 
Also please let me know ,what are some"must-know" things about tomcat ?

Comment: Please be clear if you want to develop /ehnance Tomcat or just start using it to deploy your web apps?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/ApacheTomcat/article.html.

Answer (score 2):

A few things to know about Tomcat (assuming you're an application developer who wants to build apps to run under Tomcat, not a developer who wants to work on the Tomcat project):

1. **It's a very solid piece of software**, and about as far from being a resource hog as you can get
2. **The online documentation is thin and incomplete**, especially for a product as mature and widely used as Tomcat is
3. **It uses its own classloader**, not the one that your IDE probably uses or that you use when developing, so sometimes you can get tripped up: your code will compile with no problem but you'll have problems at runtime.  I've only ever seen this become an issue when you've got two JARs, both containing the package com.foo.bar, and in one of the com.foo.bars there's a class called MyClass, but it's absent in the other com.foo.bar, and if Tomcat's classloader picks up the JAR that contains the com.foo.bar without MyClass in it, it won't go looking in any other JARs for MyClass; you'll get a runtime error).  I've also seen Tomcats of the same version that use different classloaders on different systems (things work fine on Windows but not Linux, for example).  This is all very rare, and I haven't seen it happen in Tomcat 7, and maybe not in Tomcat 6.  (It still uses its own classloader in v7, though, so this may well still be an issue.)
4. **Works well from within Eclipse** (create a "Dynamic Web Project" and run it from Eclipse, under Tomcat, making debugging easier), but it's not a perfect.  Editing a server's config from within Eclipse sometimes messes up your server.xml config file, for example (by removing custom stuff you've done, for example).  You sometimes also have to clean out Tomcat's work directory manually, which you shouldn't have to do.
5. **Is very, very widely used**, meaning someone else has always had whatever problem you have and need a solution to
6. **As with many JSP containers, Tomcat doesn't handle compile-time JSP includes perfectly.**  One shouldn't generally use those anyway (runtime includes being the way to go), but sometimes they are the right tool for the job; problem is, Tomcat doesn't always notice when you've changed a JSP that's compile-time-included.  The solution is to re-save both the including and the included file and wait a few seconds, then press reload on your browser.
7. **It's best at serving JSPs and servlets, not static files** (JavaScript, stylesheets, images, etc.); if you can, you should either put Apache in front of it (that configuration is easy, and well documented) or host your static stuff on CloudFront or similar.
8. **Plays very well with Hibernate.**
9. **Installation is extremely simple**; in the simplest case (which is often all you need, especially in a dev environment), you just unzip an archive to the directory of your choice and go.